# C++ pointer to array and for loop;

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

i'm pretty new to C++, and have a little problem with that piece of code. I want to put 1 in every cell of array which should be created with dynamic memory allocation. I believe i made something similar a few months ago in c with malloc. When I print out results (g++ Linux) it shows that only first column (when we treat every tenth cell of array as beginning of new column) is filled with ones. Others are printed as a adresses to memory.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

class TestOfForVector {
public:
double* tabX;
double* tabY;
int n;
TestOfForVector(int getN){
    n = getN;
    tabY = new double[n*n];
    //tabX = new double[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i ++ ){
        for(int j = 0; j <n; j++){
        tabY[j+i*n] = 1.0;
        std::cout<<tabY[j+i*n]<<std::endl;
        }
    }
}


~TestOfForVector(){
    delete [] tabX;
    delete [] tabY;
}
};


int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{   
TestOfForVector newboy(10); //it will be defined by user input;
return 0;
}
```

Sorry for probably trivial question, but i couldn't find answer on the internet.
Best regards,
Lukasz!

Comment: Use #include <vector> and use std::vector<double> instead of an array.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your results: http://ideone.com/VgIqt -- Are you sure this is the same code you're running?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct, and (after commenting out your `delete[] tabX` since you commented out the creation code) it runs and produces a column of ones on my machine.

I do not know what the `stdafx.h` header is supposed to be - the normal signature for `main` is `(int argc, char** argv)`. So I removed that header prior to compiling with `g++`. You said you were on Linux, so using Visual Studio things seems odd, no?

Answer (score 0):

You're running into undefined behavior in the destructor:

```
delete [] tabX;
```

because the pointer `tabX` is dangling as it's not initialized.

Besides that, your code is fine, although `stdafx.h` is the precompiled header file used under Win and `_TCHAR` is a MSVS define for a wide char and you said you're compiling under Linux.